# Allow users to specify for how long they want the shared file to be accessed by external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

We revived a requirement to implement the following scenario:-

1. Contributor user shared a file with external user.
2. the contributor users can specify for how long they want the file to
   be shared.

Is this scenario supported in SharePoint and how?

Comment: SharePoint On prem, or Online ?

Comment: @AIMENBOULAHIA Online thanks

Comment: Check my updated answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's together understand what are different sharing options that exist on SPO.

This is the option that we need to go deep through :

**Anonymous Link** : these links can only be made at the file or folders level (if permitted by your administrator). The link provided will not require any type of authentication from the recipient, who can simply click on the link and access the shared item.

[image]

**Controlling Link Expiration** : From the end user’s perspective, you are limited by your company’s sharing policies, which could go as far as preventing sharing to specific domains. Policies can also determine the lifespan of shared links; links can be set for specific durations and will automatically expire after the decided date. Once again, this is controlled by your SharePoint administrator via the SharePoint Online administration panel. By default, shared links expire after 30 days, but they can be set to an unlimited number of days.

By default, the expiring access policy is not set. A tenant or SharePoint administrator must enable it and define the sharing period in the Sharing section of the SharePoint Online admin center (Figure 1). The period can be from 30 to 730 days.

You can see further details here :

[How to Use SharePoint’s Expiring Access Policy for External Users](https://office365itpros.com/2021/11/16/sharepoint-expiring-access-policy/)

[Expiring Access Policy](https://practical365.com/guest-expiration-policy-sharepoint-online-onedrive/)

---

### THE ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION :

---

so the answer is : the scenario which each contributor can specify the expiration date **is supported** natively. please see the following process :

The settings in SP Admin Center should be like this :

[image]

Then each contributor should share a file as follow :

[image]

[image]

And then specify the Expiration date and you can even add a Password !

[image]

THIS SHOULD BE ENOUGH TO ANSWER YOUR CASE ! ^_^

Comment: The question specifically states that they need to control how long an external user can access the file, this is not supported. As you pointed out above, it's supported in the case of unauthenticated users ("anyone with a link") but not those files shared with authenticated users (external users in a directory).

Comment: I see, thanks for your explication

Answer (score 0):

No, not for a specific file (when shared with an external user). You can however set access to a site or OneDrive to expire after a set amount of days via the SharePoint admin center.

[image]

Additionally, you can set "Anyone" links to expire within a specific amount of days via the SharePoint admin center.

[image]